# How do I set a detail view's title from the selected row?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, detailsview

I have a table view made up of an NSArray of instances of a custom object. When a row in the table view is tapped, it is supposed to trigger a detail view made up of a web view.

So, in MainViewController.m, I have the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
MObjectDetailVC *mObjectDetailViewController = [[MObjectDetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MObjectDetailVC" bundle:nil];
mObjectDetailViewController.detailURL=[[[mcData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] object.url]];
mObjectDetailViewController.title=[[[mcData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] object.name]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:mObjectDetailViewController animated:YES];
[mObjectDetailViewController release];
}
```

However, I get an error for both that start with mObjectDetailViewController: `Expected ']' before '.' token.` and I don't know why. Can you help? Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I reduced the amount of square brackets, but I still have the error on each of those lines. It's just that instead of 3 of that error on each line, there's just one instance for each.

Comment: If you're still getting those errors then there probably is a syntax error elsewhere (above that function). Try copy-pasting the code I wrote below, it's easy to miss a bracket.

Comment: Okay, so I copy-pasted your code. That's actually where I'm at right now (with just 2 errors). I don't *think* it's syntax in this particular file, because it compiled fine before I added this in. Not sure though.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code I can't pinpoint its source. I'm pretty positive it's a syntax error though.

Comment: If I comment that section out and run, I get no errors and it compiles fine. So I wouldn't even know what else to show you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the lines that were giving me issue, I called `object.url` and `object.name`. This was unnecessary and invalid. I just needed to put `url` and `name` to get those variables from my selected object.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You have extra square brackets. Try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MObjectDetailVC *mObjectDetailViewController = [[MObjectDetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MObjectDetailVC" bundle:nil];
    mObjectDetailViewController.detailURL=[[[mcData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] object.url];
    mObjectDetailViewController.title=[[[mcData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] object.name];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mObjectDetailViewController animated:YES];
    [mObjectDetailViewController release];
}
```